# How to bypass the cloudflare protection?

Tags: php, api, curl, cloudflare

I need to grab some information from a site, however i cannot send requests because of the protection.
I get  **The typical Checking-your-browser** page shows up first and then i'm being redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[tamper-data]**: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

it is firefox extension you can find here how to use, you can see what exactly happend and then try to bypass it.

http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tamper_Data

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're doing may look like an attack against the site. If you want to have access to the site, then you may want to look at contacting the site owner to have them whitelist the IPs you're making the requests from.